# pandas raises value error for datetime objects

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

my dataframe has a datetime index. I can not print its info as it raises a `TypeError`:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"a": datetime.now()}, index=["a"])
print(df.info())
```

results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 88, in <module>
    print(df.info())
  File "lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2497, in info
    mem_usage = self.memory_usage(index=True, deep=deep).sum()
  File "lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2590, in memory_usage
    result = Series(self.index.memory_usage(deep=deep), index=["Index"]).append(
  File "lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 305, in __init__
    data = sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure=True)
  File "lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/construction.py", line 465, in sanitize_array
    subarr = construct_1d_arraylike_from_scalar(value, len(index), dtype)
  File "lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py", line 1452, in construct_1d_arraylike_from_scalar
    subarr = np.empty(length, dtype=dtype)
TypeError: Cannot interpret '<attribute 'dtype' of 'numpy.generic' objects>' as a data type
```

Comment: Works in pandas 1.2.0 and 1.2.2. What is your `pd.__version__`?

Comment: ah, the classic outdated version. mine is `1.0.4`

Comment: works with version `1.2.2`

Comment: Yes, but in general, the supported datetime type is `np.timedelta64` and `np.datetime64` so you can probably keep your old version (if necessary) and instead use `pd.to_datetime('now')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its worked on `pandas 1.1.4` so kindly update your `pandas` package

```
output of your code:-

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 1 entries, a to a
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------  --------------  -----         
 0   a       1 non-null      datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1)
memory usage: 16.0+ bytes
None
```